# EXC_BAD ACCESS. trying to alphabetize 10 names using pointers

Tags: c

I don't understand what the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error means.

The purpose of this code is to alphabetize 10 first names:
sort and create an array of pointers to the strings, then alphabetize by swapping the pointers not the actual strings.  When I run the code, I get `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` errors.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    char first_name[10];
    for (i=0; i <10 ; i++)
    {
        printf("please enter the number %d name: ", i);
        scanf("%s",&first_name[i]);
    }

//make pointer
    char *dummy;
    dummy = &first_name[0];
    int temp;
    int length;
    char *dummy2;
    int j;
    for (i=1; i<10;i++)
    {
        length = sizeof(first_name[i])/sizeof(char);
        dummy = &first_name[i];
        for (temp=0; temp<length;temp++)
        {
            dummy[temp] = tolower(dummy[temp]);
        }
    }
    for (i=1;i<10;i++)
    {
        dummy2 = &first_name[i];
        for (j=0;j<9;j++)
        {
            int compare = strcmp(dummy2,dummy); //This is where the bad Access error occurs.
            if (compare < 0)
            {
                temp = dummy;
                dummy = dummy2;
                dummy2 = temp;
            }
        }
        dummy = &first_name[i];
        printf("%s",dummy2);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: try `char first_name[10];` --> `char first_name[10][32];` 10 people x name (as max length 31) and `char *dummy;` --> `char *dummy[10];` 10 pointer.

Comment: Googling EXC_BAD ACCESS : 'About 21,700 results'

Comment: @ThingyWotsit: Google EXC_BAD_ACCESS and 190,000 results.

Comment: The posted code does not compile!  When compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.  1) missing statement: `#include <ctype.h>`  for the `tolower()` function.  `temp = dummy;` is 'warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast" and `dummy2 = temp;` is 'warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast'

Comment: regarding this line: `scanf("%s",&first_name[i]);`  1) first_name is only 10 chars long and a valid char string must have a terminating NUL char ('\0')   2) the input format specifier is '%s' which reads a string, not a single character AND automatically appends a NUL char to the read in string AND has not MAX CHARACTERS modifier, so the user could enter 1000 characters (with no spaces, newlines nor other 'white space' and it would happily place them all in memory, on the stack, starting at the address of `first_name`  Then the next iteration though the 'for()' loop would do it all again

Comment: the code block beginning with: `for (i=1; i<10;i++)` will skip processing of the first char in the array `first_name[]`  This is because in C, array indexing starts with 0 until (the length of the array - 1)

Comment: regarding this line: `length = sizeof(first_name[i])/sizeof(char);`  1) there are NOT multiple char arrays in `first_name`, only one array AND sizeof a single char (sizeof(first_name[i]) asks for the size of a single char)  and the expression: `sizeof( char )` is, per the C standard, 1 to the statement results in `1/1` which ALWAYs is equal to 1.  The code continues to go downhill from there.

Comment: BTW: this line: `scanf("%s",&first_name[i]);`, when 'i' == 9, will exhibit undefined behavior because even if the user only enters a single character, the '%s' will append a NUL char, which will overflow the `first_name` array, That overflow is undefined behavior and can/will lead to a seg fault event.

Answer (score 3):

The main problem is that you're passing a pointer on the same array of chars each time, just shifting the address by one:

```
scanf("%s",&first_name[i]);
```

That stores the first string in `first_name`, the second one in `first_name+1` (destroying the first string except for the first character) and ends up overwriting unallocated memory, since 1 byte is not enough to store the last item (when you reach the last item, you overflow your char array): *undefined behaviour* occurs then.

Also, computing string length with `length = sizeof(first_name[i])/sizeof(char);` is not correct. The value is 1 here, so your lowercase loop does nothing. use `strlen(first_name[i])` for that.

In the end, I suppose that you want to declare a 2D array holding 10 slots of 100-length strings:

```
char first_name[10][100];
```

And in the rest of your code replace

```
&first_name[xxx];
```

by

```
first_name[xxx];
```

to get the address of the xxxth string of your table, in a simple way.

BTW: For extra safety use a limit when doing `scanf`:

```
scanf("%99s",first_name[i]);
```

so noone can enter more than 99 chars and crash/exploit your program.